Cannot get WezTerm terminal transparent/acrylic background on Windows
I just installed WezTerm and my config looks like this :-
local wezterm = require("wezterm")

local mux = wezterm.mux

-- This will hold the configuration.

local config = wezterm.config_builder()

wezterm.on('gui-startup', function(cmd)

local tab, pane, window = mux.spawn_window(cmd or {})

window:gui_window():maximize()

end)

config.font = wezterm.font "JetBrainsMono NFM"

config.default_prog = {"C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe"}

config.window_decorations = "RESIZE"

config.window_background_opacity = 0

config.win32_system_backdrop = 'Acrylic'

return config

My problem is, even after setting my window background opacity to 0, the terminal is not transparent; I just see pure black color in the background. I tried finding this issue online but couldn't find anything related to it anywhere.
I am using:

Windows 11
WezTerm version 20240203-110809-5046fc22

I have asked this same question on their subreddit but haven't gotten any solutions yet.

Check https://github.com/wez/wezterm/issues/4145 including some comments that mention e.g. Windows setting you need to have enabled
